# npm jsonwebtoken module generates token with length 10 000

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using [jsonwebtoken v8.5.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) for generating the `accessToken` for my API.
The exact way I am using it is as follows:

```
    const accessToken = user => {
        if(user.iat)delete user.iat;
        
        return jwt.sign(user, config.ACCESS_TOKEN, { expiresIn: '10s' });
    }

//user objects has the following structure
 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f1750046e069f2e6c5b5353"
  },
  "username": "Hristo",
  "firstName": "Hristo",
  "thirdName": "Hristo",
  "startDate": "2020-07-21T20:28:35.224Z",
  "job": "Hristo",
  "secondName": "",
  "showPassword": true,
  "image": "https://placehold.it/208x208"
}
```

and the `config.ACCESS_TOKEN` is 64 bit hex string.

The lenght of the string which `jwt.sign()` returns is `10363` which is giving me the HTTP error:

> 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

when I try to make a request with header `"Authorization":accessToken`.

Any ideas what I am getting wrong?

NOTE: the experation time is `10s` for testing purposes.

The generated accessToken:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.FaHXkhO5-dBg92ZqEceruboiMFGHZ5pQanwf6bt1VG8
```

Comment: Okay thank you. I remove everything beside the `uername` in the objet passed to `jwt.sign()` is that ok?

Comment: yes, username or maybe ID. Just enough to identify to the user.

Comment: it's indeed intersting that the image was put into the token like this. When I find the time in the next days I try to find out what the jwt lib is doing there.

Comment: does your user object really contain just the image url as shown above or is the base64 string already in the database?

Comment: did you read my last question? Please repIy, I want to understand what happened.

Comment: No, no. The base64 is not from this user. The `https://placehold.it/208x208` is the default image showed for user's avatar. When they choose other avatar is replaced by it's base64 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the whole user object to the token. The user object contains an `image` property with a URL, which seems to be resolved into a base64 representation of the image in the token.

The resulting payload contains:

```
"image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...
```

That's what blows up you token.

You can inspect your token on https://jwt.io

Generally try to limit the contents of the token to the minimal necessary data that you need to identify the user. Just the ID of the user plus expiration time for a start and then build up from there (issuer, audience, roles etc.

You might also find this [introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/) useful.